# Date from string treated as wrong format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had a string value = "01/08/2021 - 31/08/2021" and i need to get the starting date using value.substring(0,10) which return as 01/08/2021. But when i converting it to date using new Date(value.substring(0,10)) it convert the date format as 2021-01-08(yyyy-mm-dd).

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split into the year, month and day

```
const [day, month, year] = value.substring(0,10).split('/');
```

Use the Date constructor

```
new Date(year, month - 1, day);
```

Comment: This will give `Sep 01 2021` in he output.

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to my notice @Nitheesh I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

[JavaScript date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#interpretation_of_two-digit_years) decodes your date string to `"mm/dd/yyyy"` format. You can simply split your date string to `month - mm`, `date - dd` and `year - yyyy` and provide this to date object.

**Please Note:** Dont forget to reduce 1 from the month number. Because JavaScript date counts month from 0 to 11.

```js
const value = "01/08/2021 - 31/08/2021";
//  const startDate = value.substring(0,10);
const [startDate, endDate] = value.split(" - ");
const [dd, mm, yyyy] = startDate.split("/");
console.log(startDate);
console.log(new Date(yyyy, +mm - 1, dd).toDateString());
```